# Stop event propagation in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-director

I'm using Corona SDK, and Director 1.4 to create an app. My goal is to open a popup when the button (`btn_play`) is clicked.

However, I encounter a problem. When the `btn_play` is clicked, it triggers `openPopup(e)` as well as `changeScene(e)` (as the background is set to execute the function). How can I stop the function `changeScene(e)` from executing when clicking the `btn_play` button?

Here is my game screen's codes:

```
module(..., package.seeall)

local localGroup

function new()
    localGroup = display.newGroup();

    -- Background Image
    local background = display.newImageRect("background.jpg", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    background:setReferencePoint( display.TopLeftReferencePoint )
    background.x, background.y = 0, 0
    background.scene = "scene_menu";

    -- Play button
    local btn_play = display.newImageRect("grass.png", 320, 82 )
    btn_play:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    btn_play.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
    btn_play.y = 600
    btn_play.scene = "inventory"

    localGroup:insert(background);
    localGroup:insert(btn_play);

    function changeScene(e)
        if(e.phase == "ended") then
            director:changeScene(e.target.scene);
        end
    end

    function openPopup(e)
        if(e.phase == "ended") then
            director:openPopUp(e.target.scene);
        end
    end

    background:addEventListener("touch", changeScene);
    btn_play:addEventListener("touch", openPopup);

    return localGroup;
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put `return` at the end of your function. It will prevent the `touch` to underlying objects.

```
function openPopup(e)
    if(e.phase == "ended") then
        director:openPopUp(e.target.scene);
        return true; -- put this in your function.
    end
end
```

Keep Coding.............. :)

Comment: very nice. it works fine ! totally overlooked the importance of `return true`

Comment: great solution ! thanks a lot. Just a question, why semicolons ?

Comment: @Rayjax: The semicolons are not mandatory. It is just used to show the line ending.

Comment: So no need to use them in lua ? You just made me doubt about it :)